# Odoo, Adding options to list (ul) in Jquery

Tags: jquery, xml, odoo-9

[xml and js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eG5Mn.png)

I have an xml and js files, as above. I want to dynamicaly add an items to list. The problem is, that JQuery wont find an element with id = "dropdown-column-view-menu". I have tryed many things, but always it's "undefined" element.

What's the way to add these elements from map called "fields"?

Comment: Could you please add the XML and the JS code to your question as a code snippet, and not as an image?

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you are creating a widget and in the start function, you are searching for the element in the DOM using the jQuery finder `$`

The thing is in the start function, the DOM has not yet been created. It resides in `this.el`.

So if you want to search for any element in the start function use `this.$el.find('YourElement')`
This is same as `this.$('YourElement')`

Comment: Thanks for reply, i will try to do that, and will see if it will work :)

Comment: If not you can drop me the error trace at sudhanshugupta7@gmail.com. I am always available there.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried binding the current context to the forEach function, and accessing the dom element through this.$buttons? Like so:

```
Object.keys(fields).forEach(function(key){        
     ...
     this.$buttons.find('#dropdown-colmn-view-menu').append(...)
     ...        
}.bind(this)); <-- BIND
```

Comment: No, i didnt. The only bind i have used is binding function to every list item in the forEach loop.